# Adapt form to Dock size (or Dock size to the size of the dock) in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, desktop-application

I am having trouble with Windows Forms in C#, I used a dock in order to show several forms when they are selects in the menu on the top of the interface, and it is OK, it shows me the form I expected but there is a little detail: The most important part of the form, where are shown the buttons that will allow you save, edit or delete are cut off even when I set up the form to fill its dock in the function to show it (it is the one called abrirForm), so I need the dock showing the full form correctly. Below are the images and the relevant code.

How you can see, I am using [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPhvg.png)s

This is [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFCFH.png)

This is the method to show the form inside the dock (the one it is called "Contenedor", and also it changes the color of the option that is pressed:

```
private void abrirForm(IconMenuItem menu, Form formulario)
        {
            if(MenuActivo != null) {
                MenuActivo.BackColor = Color.White;
            }
            menu.BackColor = Color.Silver;
            MenuActivo = menu;

            if(FormularioActivo != null)
            {
                FormularioActivo.Close();
            }
            FormularioActivo = formulario;
            formulario.TopLevel = false;
            formulario.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
            formulario.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            formulario.BackColor = Color.PaleGreen;

            Contenedor.Controls.Add(formulario);
            formulario.Show();
        }
```

This is the dock configuration in the designer.cs:

```
      this.Contenedor.AllowDrop = true;
      this.Contenedor.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Default;
      this.Contenedor.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
      this.Contenedor.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 132);
      this.Contenedor.Name = "Contenedor";
      this.Contenedor.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(918, 503);
      this.Contenedor.TabIndex = 3;
      this.Contenedor.Paint += new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler(this.Contenedor_Paint);
```

And this is the result: [The buttons are cut off from the window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5oqG.png)

Comment: The outer form simply is not big enough to fit the inner one.

Comment: It is because you are not considering the buttons area size when adding the form. by the way, why you do not use a flow layout panel as a container and USERCONTROLS instead of child forms ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case you can leverage the Controls Autosize property.

Since your child control formulario has not the size of the main Form because the extra space taken by the menu buttons what you need to do is look for a way to automatically increase the control added to the panel, fortunately there is a property Autosize as explained above and when you are adding a child control to a panel never set the child control dock to fill because it considers the main control size, so in order to fix your issue you need to do a few changes.

Remove this line:

> formulario.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

Set Autoscale for the main Form and the panel where you dinamically add controls, so add this:

> this.AutoSize = true;

> Contenedor.AutoSize = true;

So your abrirForm function will look:

```
private void abrirForm(IconMenuItem menu, Form formulario)
        {
            if(MenuActivo != null) {
                MenuActivo.BackColor = Color.White;
            }
            menu.BackColor = Color.Silver;
            MenuActivo = menu;

            if(FormularioActivo != null)
            {
                FormularioActivo.Close();
            }
            FormularioActivo = formulario;
            formulario.TopLevel = false;
            formulario.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
            //formulario.Dock = DockStyle.Fill; I COMMENTED IT, YOU NEED TO REMOVE IT
            formulario.BackColor = Color.PaleGreen;

           //SET THE AUTOSIZE in Main form and Container


                this.AutoSize = true;
                Contenedor.AutoSize = true;
                Contenedor.Controls.Add(formulario);
                formulario.Show();
            }
```

**Please notice:**

If above solution does not work is because the formulario code was not provided. Feel free to share it.

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked with this only answer you gave, so it is not neccesary to provide the form.